# Obtaining the intersections of 3-D regions using loop?

Tags: plotting, regions, inequalities

I am trying to take intersections of several three-dimensional regions by using the regionplot3d command.
Currently thinking about how to use looping to take intersections for several 3-D regions.

```
RegionPlot3D[
x - 2*(A/8)^(i) - p^(i)*(y + z) < 0 &&
x + (A/8)^(i) - p^(i)*(y + z) > 0, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2,
2}, Mesh -> None, PlotPoints -> 100]
```

The region after taking $i = 4,5,6,...,20$

any idea of looping?
$A =3, p =0.5$

Comment: `A = 3;
p = .5;
RegionPlot3D[
 And @@ Table[
   x - 2*(A/8)^(i) - p^(i)*(y + z) < 0 && 
    x + (A/8)^(i) - p^(i)*(y + z) > 0, {i, 4, 20}], {x, -5, 
  5}, {y, -5, 5}, {z, -5, 5}]`  It seems that only tiny region left.

Comment: Cool! I will have a look at the Table command used!

Comment: You can also use `RegionIntersection @@ Table[ImplicitRegion[x-2*(A/8)^(i)-p^(i)*(y+z)<0&&x+(A/8)^(i)-p^(i)*(y+z)>0, {x,y,z}], {i,4,20}]` to construct a region that matches your needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
A = 3;
p = .5;
RegionPlot3D[  And @@ Table[x - 2*(A/8)^(i) - p^(i)*(y + z) < 0 && x + (A/8)^(i) - p^(i)*(y + z) > 0, {i, 4, 20}], {x, -5,5}, {y, -5, 5}, {z, -5, 5}]
```

If we use `Reduce`,we can get some results.

```
A = 3;
p = 1/2;
sol=Reduce[And @@ 
  Table[x - 2*(A/8)^(i) - p^(i)*(y + z) < 0 && 
    x + (A/8)^(i) - p^(i)*(y + z) > 0, {i, 4, 20}], Reals]
```

```
sol=((-17692202331 - 1099511627776 z)/1099511627776 < 
    y <= (-1937102445 - 137438953472 z)/
    137438953472 && (-3486784401 + 1099511627776 y + 1099511627776 z)/
    1152921504606846976 < x < (
    387420489 + 34359738368 y + 34359738368 z)/
    9007199254740992) || ((-1937102445 - 137438953472 z)/
    137438953472 < y <= (-5811307335 - 549755813888 z)/
    549755813888 && (-3486784401 + 1099511627776 y + 1099511627776 z)/
    1152921504606846976 < x < (
    1162261467 + 137438953472 y + 137438953472 z)/
    72057594037927936) || ((-5811307335 - 549755813888 z)/
    549755813888 < y <= (5811307335 - 1099511627776 z)/
    1099511627776 && (-3486784401 + 1099511627776 y + 
     1099511627776 z)/1152921504606846976 < x < (
    3486784401 + 549755813888 y + 549755813888 z)/
    576460752303423488) || ((5811307335 - 1099511627776 z)/
    1099511627776 < y <= (1937102445 - 274877906944 z)/
    274877906944 && (-1162261467 + 274877906944 y + 274877906944 z)/
    144115188075855872 < x < (
    3486784401 + 549755813888 y + 549755813888 z)/
    576460752303423488) || ((1937102445 - 274877906944 z)/
    274877906944 < y <= (645700815 - 68719476736 z)/
    68719476736 && (-387420489 + 68719476736 y + 68719476736 z)/
    18014398509481984 < x < (
    3486784401 + 549755813888 y + 549755813888 z)/
    576460752303423488) || ((645700815 - 68719476736 z)/68719476736 < 
    y < (36546666129 - 3848290697216 z)/
    3848290697216 && (-129140163 + 17179869184 y + 17179869184 z)/
    2251799813685248 < x < (
    3486784401 + 549755813888 y + 549755813888 z)/576460752303423488)
```

And we can test the solution which provided by @UlrichNeumann

```
sol/. {x -> 0, y -> c, z -> -c} // Simplify
(* True *)
```

```
RegionPlot3D[sol, {x, -.1, .1}, {y, -.1, .1}, {z, -.1, .1}]
```

[image]

Comment: Mathematica v12 only plots some points as resulting region. The resulting region should be `x==0 &&y==-z` I think.

Comment: @UlrichNeumann,  Yes, `sol /. {x -> 0, y -> c, z -> -c} // Simplify`  means that this is one of the solution but not all the solution.

Comment: Ok, but my question concerns the resulting regionplot in your answer. Mathematica v12 only shows some points! That's quite unexpected because RegionPlot3D usually shows 3D subregions. Please show your resulting plot. Thanks!

Comment: @UlrichNeumann Thanks, I have already updated.